# Roboto Font from Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, fonts

Is it possible to separately download and use the Roboto font from Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) announced today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download them from the Android Design website, here:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Answer (score 3):

Welp, this is not a programming question. However,

[Here is a link](http://bandbinnovations.com/xda/Roboto-Fonts.zip)

Mirror : [here](http://db.tt/bTJM9zRA)

---

Edit: For completeness sake: Android Design's [Typography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html)

Answer (score 1):

All of the fonts on Android are shipped as .ttf files. You can find them in Android's git repo under android/platform/frameworks/base.git/data/fonts. Once the ICS source code is online, you'll find it there.

Alternatively, you can extract it from the emulator image. Fonts are stored in /system/fonts.

(There's also a good chance it will get uploaded to Google Web Fonts soon, since Droid Sans is already there.)